Uppy could not read Location/ETag header although I can see headers listed in response headers
I'm trying to implement direct uploads to a DigitalOcean bucket. The direct uploads work just fine, and I can see the file uploaded in the bucket. However, after the upload, I get these errors:

I can see both the ETag and Location headers listed in the response headers, but I don't know why I'm getting these errors in the console. I've been struggling with this for whole day, trying to figure it out.
This is what my CORSConfiguration looks like:
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
  <CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:5000</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>x-amz-date</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>x-amz-content-sha256</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>content-type</AllowedHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>Location</ExposeHeader>
  </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>

This is my js controller that handles direct upload:
import {Uppy} from "@uppy/core";
import AwsS3 from "@uppy/aws-s3";

export default class extends Controller {
    static targets = ["input", "preview", "hidden"];

    connect() {
        this.uppy = new Uppy({
            autoProceed: true
        });

        this.uppy.use(AwsS3, {
            endpoint: "/" // Shrine presigned URL endpoint
        });
      
        this.uppy.on("upload-success", (file, response) => {
            console.log(file.name, response.uploadURL); // I cant reach this line I think is due to errors in console
            const uploadedFileData = JSON.stringify({
                id: file.meta["key"].match(/^cache\/(.+)/)[1],
                storage: "cache",
                metadata: {
                    size: file.size,
                    filename: file.name,
                    mime_type: file.type
                }
            });
            
            this.hiddenTarget.value = uploadedFileData;
            // Display the uploaded image in the preview
            this.previewTarget.src = URL.createObjectURL(file.data);
            this.previewTarget.closest(".profile-logo__preview").classList.remove("d-none");
        });
    }
    
    //this is executed when I select file
    selectFile(event) {
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        if (file) {
            this.uppy.addFile({
                name: file.name,
                type: file.type,
                data: file
            });
        }
    }
}

Versions:
"@uppy/aws-s3": "^4.1.3",
"@uppy/core": "^4.3.0",
Maybe I just forgot something to set up properly but I cant see any issue here..
Thanks for any help in advance.
